# keyCodes for Arabic letters for android

Tags: android, xml

In creating a custom keyboard in android, the xml file that contain the keyCodes like this has somelines like this:

what is 56 represent ?? and where can I get all the codes for all the letters English and other languages?
and what if I want to add an Arabic letters to the keyboard next to English letters ? I didn't find the keyCodes for the Arabic letters.

Example in the link
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/res/xml/qwerty.xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can this code. It includes all Arabic letter.

```
 <Row>
        <Key android:codes="1590" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:keyLabel="ض" />
        <Key android:codes="1589" android:keyLabel="ص" />
        <Key android:codes="1579" android:keyLabel="ث" />
        <Key android:codes="1602" android:keyLabel="ق" />
        <Key android:codes="1601" android:keyLabel="ف" />
        <Key android:codes="1594" android:keyLabel="غ" />
        <Key android:codes="1593" android:keyLabel="ع" />
        <Key android:codes="1607" android:keyLabel="ه" />
        <Key android:codes="1582" android:keyLabel="خ" />
        <Key android:codes="1581" android:keyLabel="ح" />
        <Key android:codes="1580" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" android:keyLabel="ج" />
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="1588" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:keyLabel="ش" />
        <Key android:codes="1587" android:keyLabel="س" />
        <Key android:codes="1610" android:keyLabel="ي" />
        <Key android:codes="1576" android:keyLabel="ب" />
        <Key android:codes="1604" android:keyLabel="ل" />
        <Key android:codes="1575" android:keyLabel="ا" />
        <Key android:codes="1578" android:keyLabel="ت" />
        <Key android:codes="1606" android:keyLabel="ن" />
        <Key android:codes="1605" android:keyLabel="م" />
        <Key android:codes="1603" android:keyLabel="ك" />
        <Key android:codes="1731" android:keyLabel="ۃ" />
    </Row>
    <Row android:keyWidth="8.800006%p">
        <Key android:codes="1569" android:keyLabel="ء" />
        <Key android:codes="1592" android:keyLabel="ظ" />
        <Key android:codes="1591" android:keyLabel="ط" />
        <Key android:codes="1586" android:keyLabel="ز" />
        <Key android:codes="1583" android:keyLabel="د" />
        <Key android:codes="1584" android:keyLabel="ذ" />
        <Key android:codes="1585" android:keyLabel="ر" />
        <Key android:codes="1608" android:keyLabel="و" />
        <Key android:codes="8216" android:keyLabel="‘" />
        <Key android:keyWidth="12.0%p" android:codes="-5" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" android:isModifier="true" android:isRepeatable="true" android:keyIcon="@drawable/btn_back" />
    </Row>
```

Comment: also you have missed "1609" for "ى"

Answer (score 2):

in your example link, these integer code is relate to standard decimal ascii code. for example 56 is "8" carachter. you can find this code and symbole in this [link](http://www.ascii-code.com/). but in standard ascii you cant find arabic symbol or other language like persian and .... and you have to use utf-8 standard. for using utf8 use this [link](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0600-06FF)

Comment: so lets say I want the code for the letter "ب"
as the link say the UTF-8 for this letter is "0628"
so the xml code should be
<Key android:codes="0628" android:keyLabel="ب" />
am I right??

Answer (score 2):

Here is the qwerty.xml, Make a folder named XML in res folder, and add qwerty.xml Keyboard Layout. The layout includes all Arabic letter:

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keyWidth="10%p"
android:horizontalGap="0px"
android:verticalGap="0px"   
android:keyHeight="60dp"
android:id="@+id/ArabicKeyboard"

>
<Row>
    <Key android:codes="1590" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:keyLabel="ض" />
    <Key android:codes="1589" android:keyLabel="ص" />
    <Key android:codes="1579" android:keyLabel="ث" />
    <Key android:codes="1602" android:keyLabel="ق" />
    <Key android:codes="1601" android:keyLabel="ف" />
    <Key android:codes="1594" android:keyLabel="غ" />
    <Key android:codes="1593" android:keyLabel="ع" />
    <Key android:codes="1607" android:keyLabel="ه" />
    <Key android:codes="1582" android:keyLabel="خ" />
    <Key android:codes="1581" android:keyLabel="ح" />
    <Key android:codes="1580" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" android:keyLabel="ج" />
</Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="1588" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:keyLabel="ش" />
        <Key android:codes="1587" android:keyLabel="س" />
        <Key android:codes="1610" android:keyLabel="ي" />
        <Key android:codes="1576" android:keyLabel="ب" />
        <Key android:codes="1604" android:keyLabel="ل" />
        <Key android:codes="1575" android:keyLabel="ا" />
        <Key android:codes="1578" android:keyLabel="ت" />
        <Key android:codes="1606" android:keyLabel="ن" />
        <Key android:codes="1605" android:keyLabel="م" />
        <Key android:codes="1603" android:keyLabel="ك" />
        <Key android:codes="1731" android:keyLabel="ۃ" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="-1" android:keyLabel="CHANGE" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="1569" android:keyLabel="ء" />
        <Key android:codes="1592" android:keyLabel="ظ" />
        <Key android:codes="1591" android:keyLabel="ط" />
        <Key android:codes="1586" android:keyLabel="ز" />
        <Key android:codes="1583" android:keyLabel="د" />
        <Key android:codes="1584" android:keyLabel="ذ" />
        <Key android:codes="1585" android:keyLabel="ر" />
        <Key android:codes="1608" android:keyLabel="و" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>


    </Row>


<Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
    <Key android:codes="1609" android:keyLabel="ى" android:keyWidth="10%p"  android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="47" android:keyLabel="/" android:keyWidth="10%p" />
    <Key android:codes="32" android:keyLabel="SPACE" android:keyWidth="60%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
    <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyLabel="DEL" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:isRepeatable="true" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>

</Row> </Keyboard>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use custom like this

```
 <Key android:codes="1136" android:keyLabel="أ" android:keyOutputText="أ"/>
```

or hex directly like this

```
<Key android:codes="0x0641" android:keyLabel="\u0641"/>
```

or compute from hex to decimal using any convertor and do multiple on the same one like this

```
<Key android:codes="1571,1573" android:keyLabel="إ أ"/>
```

just make sure you use Keyboard with a capital K not a small k for the initial

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"...
```

I tried many solutions and so much time but none worked because of that stupid mistake